# One table or two tables?

Tags: database-design

If one table, let's call it `table_1`, has a composite alternate key made up of `field1` and `version`, is it considered denormalized data, since `field1` is repeating itself in the table (multiple rows with same value for `field1` but different value in `version`), and thus `field1` shall be extracted to another table, let's  call it `table_2`, so `table_2` will have two columns `field_1` and `field_1_id`, and replace `field1` in `table_2` with `field_1_id`?

#### Considerations

I think one table is a better design, but someone is suggesting me to have two tables, the reason is the duplication of values in `field1`, but even with two tables, the `field_1_id` will still be duplicated, right?

Comment: Consider that, instead of having repeated values of field1, the new table will have repeated values of field1_id. Do you think that something is changed about normalization?

Comment: No, wrong. Simply use a realistic example, natural language and logic to design -- the rest will take care of itself. It is extremely easy to get bogged down in "generic" examples and mind-numbing terminology. Take a look at this:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215868/what-is-the-correct-way-of-creating-a-one-to-one-relationship/

Comment: .. (cont) Keep in mind that DB design is **predicate design** -- so to have redundancy you have to repeat a whole predicate -- not a value of a single attribute.